# Access view configuration from renderer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

Is there a way to access the view configuration from a renderer? By view configuration I mean the arguments passed to the [view_config()](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/view.html#pyramid.view.view_config) decorator. My goal is to add some settings to the view configuration which a renderer can then use.

I have a custom renderer:

```
class MyRenderer(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        pass

    def __call__(self, value, system):
        # Get view options.
        my_renderer_opts = ...

        # Render using options.
        ...
```

which is registered as:

```
config.add_renderer('my_renderer', MyRenderer)
```

Then in my view I have:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @pyramid.view.view_config(
        route_name='root',
        renderer='my_renderer',
        my_renderer_opts={...}
    )
    def view(self):
        pass
```

Is there a way to access `my_renderer_opts` passed to `view_config()` from `MyRenderer.__call__()`?

Comment: `my_renderer_opts` can be added via View Predicate https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#adding-a-third-party-view-route-or-subscriber-predicate, Renderer have access to request/view/view_name etc, check `pyramid.interfaces.RendererHelper.render_view`, predicates available in `view.__predicates__ `

Comment: @slav0nic How would I add `my_renderer_opts` using a predicate? I've used a predicate but not in this context before. I've been looking at the source of `RendererHelper` without any luck. `system['view']` is an instance of `Page` but it has no `__predicates__` attribute (tested on a view that actually has a predicate unlike my example).

Comment: ops, sorry,  I got it mixed up with `deriver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you still want implement it as described, maybe `deriver` will be helpfull:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.config import Configurator


@view_config(route_name="hello", renderer="myrend", renderer_options={"a": 1})
def hello_world(request):
    return "Hello World!"


def rendereropt_deriver(view, info):
    options = info.options.get("renderer_options", {})

    def wrapped(context, request):
        setattr(request, "_renderer_options", options)
        return view(context, request)
    return wrapped


rendereropt_deriver.options = ("renderer_options",)


class MyRendererFactory:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info

    def __call__(self, value, system):
        options = getattr(system["request"], "_renderer_options", {})
        print("`renderer_options` is {}".format(options))
        return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route("hello", "/")
        config.add_view_deriver(rendereropt_deriver)
        config.add_renderer("myrend", MyRendererFactory)
        config.scan(".")
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server("0.0.0.0", 8000, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```